# pandas.read_csv() strange behavior for empty (default) values

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have following input trans.csv file:

```
Date,Currenncy,Symbol,Type,Units,UnitPrice,Cost,Tax
2012-03-14,USD,AAPL,BUY,1000
2012-05-12,USD,SBUX,SELL,500
```

The fields UnitPrice, Cost and Tax are optional. If they are not specified I expect NaN in the DataFrame cell.

I read the csv file with:

```
t = pandas.read_csv('trans.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
```

and got the following result:

```
           Currenncy Symbol  Type  Units   UnitPrice       Cost       Tax
Date                                                                     
2012-03-14       USD   AAPL   BUY   1000  2012-05-12  012-05-12  12-05-12
2012-02-05       USD   SBUX  SELL    500         NaN        NaN       NaN
```

Why are there no NaN in the first row and is the Date repeated?
Any workaround to get NaN for the unspecified fields?

Comment: Added this as an [issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2668). The answer I posted should fix it for now (it catches when there is data in some of the columns)...

Answer (score 3):

Your CSV file is malformed. I get the same answer as you in Pandas 0.10, and while I admit that it is indeed very, very strange, you shouldn't be feeding it malformed data.

```
Date,Currenncy,Symbol,Type,Units,UnitPrice,Cost,Tax
2012-03-14,USD,AAPL,BUY,1000,,,
2012-05-12,USD,SBUX,SELL,500,,,
```

returns the expected

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> t = pd.read_csv('pandas_test', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
>>> t
           Currenncy Symbol  Type  Units  UnitPrice  Cost  Tax
Date                                                          
2012-03-14       USD   AAPL   BUY   1000        NaN   NaN  NaN
2012-05-12       USD   SBUX  SELL    500        NaN   NaN  NaN
```

Comment: That's one comma too much, now there are NaN Units, without an error message! Can the extra commas not be made optional by pandas. Looks cleaner.

Comment: "Looks cleaner". Why do you care what the original data looks like if you're parsing it? It doesn't matter that it looks cleaner if it's incorrect.

Comment: @hayden, indeed feeding malformed data is life. Can't we expect from pandas that this is handled gracefully ? It's not that malformed.

Comment: @rdw I think so. It looks like a bug.

Comment: "that malformed". Being malformed is binary, it's malformed or it isn't malformed.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like a bug

Comment: @rdw or at least: "feature worth having" :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method which can handle some more cases (when there is some data in `UnitCost`, `Cost`, etc.).

```
In [1]: df = pd.read_csv('trans.csv', header=None)

In [2]: df.columns = df.ix[0]

In [3]: df[1:].set_index('Date')
Out[3]: 
           Currenncy Symbol  Type Units UnitPrice Cost  Tax
Date                                                       
2012-03-14       USD   AAPL   BUY  1000       NaN  NaN  NaN
2012-05-12       USD   SBUX  SELL   500       NaN  NaN  NaN
2012-05-12       USD   SBUX  SELL   500       NaN  NaN  NaN
```

It's worth noting that the dtype of the these columns will be `object`.

*However, I think this should be caught by [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) so I posted as [an issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2668).*